# Seeing if a database line exists matching two foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called alpha. Another model, beta, has the foreign keys of alpha and gamma. I'd like to see if beta exists for a given alpha and gamma match, so I tried doing it like this for an instance of alpha named 'a' and a gamma named 'g' but it doesn't work because it doesn't know to look at the gamma for each beta for some reason. I can put it in a nasty loop, but that seems very un-RoR.

```
a.betas.gamma.includes?(g)
```

I also tried various forms of `a.betas.find(:gamma => g)`

Those also do not work. Am I just suppose to move everything into the betas model and make it a class method of beta? That seems remarkably inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right:

```
class Alpha << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :betas
end

class Beta << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alpha
  belongs_to :gamma
end

class Gamma << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :betas
end
```

Can you add `has_many :gammas, :through => :beta` to the Alpha class? If so, then try:

```
a.gammas.exists?(g)
```

Comment: D'oh! I knew rails wanted to help me somehow... Thank you!